# WebpackError: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'closeDropDownHandler' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am running into an issue in developing on Gatsby where my code is working fine in development mode but when I do a production build I am getting an error that I can't seem to solve.

```
age data from page-data.json for the failed page "/blogs/": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-blogs-js",
  "path": "/blogs/",
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {}
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": []
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 7.021s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/blogs/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  11 |
  12 | const Navbar = () => {
> 13 |   const ref = useDetectClickOutside({ onTriggered: closeDropDownHandler });
     |                                                    ^
  14 |
  15 |   const [activeDropDown, setActiveDropDown] = useState(false);
  16 |   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'closeDropDownHandler' before initialization
```

Here is my full source code for Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BiSearch } from "react-icons/bi";
import { BiCurrentLocation } from "react-icons/bi";
import Drawer from "react-modern-drawer";
import "react-modern-drawer/dist/index.css";
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import SPORTISTA from "../../images/logo.svg";
import { useDetectClickOutside } from 'react-detect-click-outside';
import { GrClose } from 'react-icons/gr';


const Navbar = () => {
  const ref = useDetectClickOutside({ onTriggered: closeDropDownHandler });

  const [activeDropDown, setActiveDropDown] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };
  const dropDownHandler = () => {
    setActiveDropDown(!activeDropDown)
  }
  const closeDropDownHandler = () => {
    setActiveDropDown(false)
  }
  return (
    <div className="w-full" >
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="hidden lg:flex justify-between items-center py-8">
          <div>
            <img className="cursor-pointer" src={SPORTISTA} alt="Sportista" />
          </div>
          <div onClick={dropDownHandler}>
            <div class="relative max-w-[400px] min-w-[300px] flex border px-3 rounded-md">
              <div class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-700">
                <a className="text-2xl text-gray-400">
                  <BiSearch />
                </a>
              </div>
              
              <div class="appearance-none block w-full text-gray-700  rounded py-3 px-4 pl-10 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white">
                <a>Sport</a>
              </div>
              <div
                className="flex items-center gap-6 cursor-pointer"
              >
                <a className="text-3xl text-gray-500">
                  <BiCurrentLocation />
                </a>
                <a>Location</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="flex gap-10 text-base items-center">
            <a className="cursor-pointer">Explore</a>
            <a className="cursor-pointer">Blog</a>
            <a className="cursor-pointer">Contact</a>
            <a className="cursor-pointer nav-btn text-white px-10 py-2 rounded">
              Add Listing
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-6 lg:hidden">
          <img
            className="cursor-pointer w-32"
            src={SPORTISTA}
            alt="Sportista"
          />
          <a className="text-xl font-medium" onClick={toggleDrawer}>
            <GiHamburgerMenu />
          </a>
        </div>
        {activeDropDown && (
          
          <div className=" relative" ref={ref}>
            <div className=" bg-white absolute px-8 py-8 shadow-2xl rounded-sm  w-full">
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center border-b">
              <h1 className=" py-5 text-2xl font-bold text-[#3D73FF]">
                Sport to play
              </h1>
              <a onClick={closeDropDownHandler} className="text-xl cursor-pointer font-semibold"><GrClose/></a>
              </div>
              <div className="md:flex gap-10 w-full items-center mt-8 md:mt-4">
                <div class="relative max-w-[300px] min-w-[300px]">
                  <label className="text-white w-full">
                    What Sport or Organization?
                  </label>
                  <select
                    class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 mt-2 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                    id="grid-state"
                  >
                    <option>Select Sports</option>
                    <option>Cricket</option>
                    <option>Football</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 mt-8 text-gray-700">
                    <svg
                      class="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    >
                      <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="relative max-w-[300px] min-w-[300px] md:mb-0 mb-8">
                  <label className="text-white">What City/State?</label>
                  <select
                    class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 mt-2 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                    id="grid-state"
                  >
                    <option>Select City</option>
                    <option>Missouri</option>
                    <option>Texas</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 mt-8 text-gray-700">
                    <svg
                      class="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    >
                      <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a className="cursor-pointer nav-btn text-white px-10 py-[10px] mt-8 rounded">
                  Search
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
     
        )}
        <Drawer
          open={isOpen}
          onClose={toggleDrawer}
          direction="left"
          className=""
        >
          <div>
            <div className="text-base responsive-menu px-4 pt-10">
              <a className="cursor-pointer">Explore</a>
              <a className="cursor-pointer">Blog</a>
              <a className="cursor-pointer">Contact</a>
              <a className="cursor-pointer nav-btn text-white px-4 py-2 rounded max-w-[150px] text-center">
                Add Listing
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And here is my package.json

```
"name": "sportista-gatsby",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "sportista-gatsby",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby": "^4.24.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.24.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.24.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.24.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.24.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-detect-click-outside": "1.1.7",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-modern-drawer": "^1.1.2",
    "react-outside-click-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^5.24.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

I tried to create a new component for dropdown that was in the documentation for "react-detect-click-outside"
https://github.com/zhaluza/react-detect-click-outside

That seemed to get rid of the error but now my dropdown doesn't work.

Comment: You are trying to access the function before initialization

Answer (score 1):

Create the function before using it

```
  const closeDropDownHandler = () => {
    setActiveDropDown(false)
  }
  const ref = useDetectClickOutside({ onTriggered: closeDropDownHandler });
  const [activeDropDown, setActiveDropDown] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };
  const dropDownHandler = () => {
    setActiveDropDown(!activeDropDown)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that prior and that gets rid of the error but the dropdown doesn't appear when I click. It's weird.

Comment: I think I found a solution, it works but I'm going to continue testing:
`let closeDropDownHandler;
const ref = useDetectClickOutside({ onTriggered: closeDropDownHandler });
closeDropDownHandler = () ....`